# Is the optimal solution of the tsp for a random set of n points in the eucleadean plane always a simple polygon?

Tags: graph-theory, np-complete

For me a simple polygon in the euclidean plane just means that it is like a piece of paper. The only constraints are that the paper has to be unfolded, cant have a hole in the middle and can only have straight edges.

So the question is if the optimal solution of the traveling salesman problem for any set of **n** points is such a polygon.

If it is, I would like to know how fast the number of simple polygons that can be created with n points, grows with n. Espacially in worst case. Up until 10 it grows slower then **n^4** for random points so avg case.

If it's not I would like to see a counterexample.

Is there an algorithm to generate all polygons of that kind out of n random points?

Comment: Presumably this is then about the special case where the graph vertices each have 2D coordinates and the weight of the edge between any two vertices is the Euclidean distance between their coordinates.

Comment: If this is about joining $n>2$ points in a plane with a single cycle, then the answer is $\frac{n!}{2n}$ (order the points on the cycle, and adjust for being able to start at any point and go in either direction), though many of these will have crossing lines.  This grows faster than an exponential function and much faster than $n^4$

Comment: Yes, an optimal solution of a 2D tsp problem will never have crossing lines, so is a simple polygon. If you want to count only such polygons, then you can arrange $3n$ points as $n$ concentric similar triangles, and establish that there are at least $2^{n-1}$ simple polygons to choose from, so it is at least exponential in $n$.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Yes it is about this special case that uses euclidean distance, still it is np complete. I dont understand your second comment. How do you arrange those 3n points? In the end this is what I want though. Some form of formula to calculate how many possible solutions without crossing lines there are for a given n.
Is there a proof that the optimal solution can't have crossing lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easy to see (by the triangle inequality applied in two quarters) that the sum of the lengths of the diagonals of any convex quadrilateral is longer than the sum of the lengths of a pair of opposite sides.  Consequently, the shortest Hamiltonian cycle through a set of points in the plane does not contain any crossing edges.

$n = 10$ is tiny: $n^4$ looks much larger than $2^n$ on that range, for example.  It's easy to construct arrangements of points with on which you can explicitly construct exponentially many noncrossing Hamiltonian cycles (for example: given any arrangement of $n$ points, replace each point with four tightly clustered points; then any noncrossing Hamiltonian cycle in the original graph can be lifted to at least $2^n$ Hamiltonian cycles in the inflated graph) and there is no reason to think that random collections of points have lots of extra constraints.

OTOH there are good approximations for TSP in the Euclidean setting, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem#Euclidean

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know 10 is tiny but the proportion of solutions without crossing lines is decreasing with higher n. Since for higher n there are a lot more solutions with crossing lines then without them.

Comment: Is there a way to calculate out off all possible sets of n points in the 2d plane the arrangement of n points that has the highest number of solutions without crossing lines?

Comment: That's an interesting question, and I have no idea.  I tried putting a bunch of keywords into my favorite search engine, and it produced
https://doi.org/10.1016/j.dam.2005.12.010
This does not answer your question, but perhaps it suggests a body of literature through which you could try reference-hunting.

Comment: This paper explains it.
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1109.5596.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Yes indeed, the solution to a tsp (symmetric in Euclidean plane) will always be a simple polygon. I believe this is quoted in Applegate et al. book on the TSP, but I cannot remember the page number.

The problem is that the number of simple polygons with n vertices is c^n where c is a constant. Several research papers have been written on max and min values of c, which range from 4.6 on the minimum side to 56 on the maximum. So, you can imagine that even 4^10 is quite a few simple polygons to search for "the one", so still quite a needle in a haystack.

Comment: Interesting. I still believe it might be possible to reduce this further. I mean not every kind of simple polygon is actually suitable to be the solution to a tsp. But probably it will still be exponential growing with n.